# Problema com leitura de arquivos em Java

Tags: java

Eu tenho um módulo em uma aplicação em *Java* que faz a leitura e processamento de arquivos **.xls**, **.xlsx** e **.csv**.

É uma aplicação web, onde o usuário faz upload de um arquivo com algum destes formatos, via rest, e quando o arquivo está no servidor, minha aplicação Java o processa.

Este processo consta em ler o arquivo, varrer campo por campo, ou coluna por coluna, pegar os dados, para inseri-los na base de dados. Até este momento não tenho nenhum problema. Consegui fazer minha aplicação funcionar corretamente, utilizando o **APACHE-POI**.

O grande problema é que um dos arquivos que o usuário precisa importar para a minha aplicação processar, é gerado por um SAP. E ele é salvo como **.xls**, porem na hora que minha aplicação tenta ler o arquivo ele me traz a exceção:

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid header signature; read 0x0020000A000DFEFF, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document
```

E pelo que pesquisei, essa exceção diz que o meu arquivo **.xls, não é um arquivo .xls.**

Andei pesquisando, e é como se o SAP exportasse um arquivo **.csv**, porem ele envia com a extensão .xls. Caso eu abro o arquivo e dou um salvar como **.xls**, ou **.csv**, o o processo funciona corretamente.

Uma alternativa a solução que eu pensei, foi, caso seja um **.xls**, e ocorra esta exceção em especial, eu envio o arquivo para o método que lê o **.csv** e ele processa. Literalmente funcionou, consigo "ler" o arquivo, mas não consigo extrair os dados, pois aparentemente o arquivo não tem o delimitador de campos definido.

**[UPDATE]**

[image: Inspect via debug]
Consegui pegar o campo correto setando o delimitador como **Tab**. Conforme a imagem, na hora do debug, o valor do campo[i] está vazio, e dentro dele tenho o "value", que é realmente o valor que eu preciso. Porém não tenho ideia de como pegar este valor, alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Sua abordagem está correta. Você pode abrir o arquivo .csv em um editor de texto e verificar se o delimitador está posicionado corretamente no  arquivo. Em arquivos .csv, o delimitador é a vírgula.

Comment: @BernardoBotelho Obrigado pela ajuda, porem abri o arquivo (xls, como ele vem) no editor de texto, e não  tem delimitador. Este é o meu grande problema. Se for totalmente impossível isso, infelizmente vou ter que apelar para o usuário abrir o arquivo e ir em salvar como, rs, mas isso não seria legal.

Comment: Talvez o delimitador seja espaços ou tabs?

Comment: @BernadorBotelho Caso o delimitador seja o tab, sabe me dizer como posso setá-lo? Tentei por espaço e não deu certo. Uma coisa um pouco ruim, é que dessa forma, caso algum registro o campo esteja vazio, os demais campos vem 'uma casa' antes. O negócio é realmente muito complicado.

Comment: Vai depender como você está fazendo a leitura do arquivo. Se você está utilizando split, use assim: arquivo.split("\t").

Comment: @BernardoBotelho fiz um teste melhor, e vi que consegui pegar os campos, utilizando o tab, obrigado, porém agora consegui enxergar o problema, de porque está vindo os campos vazios. Atualizei a pergunta inserido um print do inspect.

Comment: Se for um CSV mesmo, melhor seria você descobrir qual é o delimitador (inspecionando no notepad++) e abrindo com superCSV ou algo do tipo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver, neste caso em especial este arquivo, que é na verdade um .csv, porem com a extensão .xls, eu utilizei um método já desenvolvido antes para leitura de arquivos csv e deu certo. Conseguindo assim extrair os dados do arquivo e inserir em uma base de dados.